# sharepoint 2010 list pages and subsites not inheriting master page

Tags: css

I am having trouble getting the pages for Lists to inherit the master page - my custom banner does not show when I click a list.
Also, the subsites do not inherit this page, even when I select it specifically for that site by pasting the layouts/changesitemasterpage.aspx

Any idea why?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the issue was that when I added the master page URL I included the css file with a url like /../../styles.css , which only works for the top level site, but list pages and subsites, they are at a different heirarchy so the css can't be found.  Resolved by adding the css file to the styles library at top level site, giving everyone read access, then using /styles library/styles.css in the master page

Answer (score 0):

Is the site/site collection you are trying to apply the master page to using publishing? Are you running Foundation/Standard/Enterprise?